# Is it possible to use wood chips on an electric grill to get a more smoky flavour?

Tags: grilling, smoking

There's a ton of content out there about smoking meat on a gas grill using a smoker box, or even gas BBQs that come with a built-in smoker box. Is the same possible with an electric grill?

If so, what's the best way to achieve a good, smoky flavour on an electric grill? I imagine it'll always be lacking in some part compared to gas or charcoal, but can it come close?

Comment: A lot of smokers are electric these days... it's just a hot plate with a place to put wood chips, and a box to contain the smoke.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[There](https://amazingribs.com/ratings-reviews/how-buy-smoker/electric-smokers) [are](https://www.thespruceeats.com/best-electric-smokers-4159127) [electric](https://www.smokedbbqsource.com/best-electric-smokers/) smokers available.  Whether a particular electric *grill* is suitable depends on the grill, but I don't think there is a reason not to try an aluminium foil pouch of wood chips on it.  In fact, [here](https://cookoutexpert.com/how-to-smoke-meat-on-electric-grill/) is a site describing how to use an electric grill for that purpose.